@Cacheable on Service class method with String param: "annotation @Cacheable is disallowed for this location"/"cannot convert from String to boolean"
I want to place a @Cacheable("zip-city-state") on a Service class method which take a String parameter of zipcode.  Calls to the method with the same input parameter should be cached. This Service method will call a number of DAO or StoredProcedure methods inside itself.
From my understanding, I shouldn't have to specify any additional condition=".." annotations, everything should be automatic. It's clear that the String param is the key.
   @Service
   public class AddressService {

      @Cacheable("zip-city-state")
      public CityState getCityState(String zipcode) {
         // ... DAO calls
         // ... Stored Procedure calls
         return cityStateResult;
      }

2 errors:

The annotation @Cacheable is disallowed for this location (on
@Cacheable)
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean
(on the input param)


SOLVED
My import was incorrect - Jakarta Persistence rather than import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;.
